# Error While opening InfoWindow (google maps api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I got an error "**Cannot read property 'open' of undefined**" while trying to open an InfoWindow in Google Maps API. But when i'm calling *infoWindows[i].setMap(map)* outside of '*marker[i].addListener*' everything is okay. Here's my code

```
var devices = new Array();
var marker = new Array();
var infoWindows = new Array();
devices = <?= json_encode($devices); ?>
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: {lat: 49.062415, lng: 31.704558},
        zoom: 6,
    });
    initMarkers();
}

function initMarkers(){
    for(var i=0; i< devices.length; i++){
        marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: parseFloat(devices[i]['lat']), lng: 
                parseFloat(devices[i]['lon'])
            },
            map: map,
            icon: mIcon,
        });
        infoWindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: devices[i]['infoData']});
        marker[i].setMap(map);
        marker[i].addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindows[i].open(map, marker[i]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Scope closure issue - that `i` that you're using in `marker[i]` doesn't refer to what you wish it did anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a scope closure issue - you can fix it by invoking a function so that `i` stays the same, but you should read up on it a bit too.

```
marker[i].addListener('click', function (val) {
    return function () {
        infoWindows[val].open(map, marker[val]);
    };
}(i));
```